# Como evitar volver a cargar datos en la base de datos luego de recargar el Navegador

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Cada vez que recargo el navegador luego de insertar los datos en la BD, me vuelve a ingresar los mismos datos que envie y no entiendo el porque.

Tengo la siguiente consulta `SQL` en `PHP`:

```
<?php
    $user = "root";
    $password = "";
    $host = "localhost";
    $db = "usuarios";

    $conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=utf8", $user, $password);

    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $apellido = $_POST['apellidos'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO usuario (nombre,apellidos) VALUES (?,?)";
    $stid = $conexion->prepare($sql);
    $stid->bindParam(1,$nombre, PDO::PARAM_STR, 50);
    $stid->bindParam(2,$apellido, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stid->execute();
    $stid->closeCursor();

?>
```

**Tabla en la Base de Datos**

```
CREATE TABLE usuario (
    id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL ,
    nombre varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    apellidos varchar(100) NOT NULL,

   CONSTRAINT pk_usuarios PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Comment: Cuando pulsas en recargar ¿Te aparece una alerta diciendo "¿Seguro que quieres volver a enviar...?"?

Comment: @BrahimKhallota no, no me aparece nada, solo recarga y ya

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En primer lugar, estás ejecutando el `INSERT` todo el rato, sin importar si el usuario ha enviado el formulario o no. Para ello haz que todo el código PHP que has compartido esté dentro de este `if`:

```
if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
  // Código
}
```

Y luego, en el botón que usas para enviar el formulario, añade `name="enviar"`:

```
<button type="submit" name="enviar">Enviar formulario</button>
```

Ahora solo se hará el insert si has enviado el formulario, pero queda otra cosa, y es que si pulsan en recargar después de enviar el formulario, es posible que se haga nuevamente el registro (*si se pulsa "Aceptar" en la alerta*).

Para resolverlo puedes hacer una de estas cosas:

- Redirige a otra página después de hacer el **INSERT**.
- Marca uno de los campos como `UNIQUE` desde la base de datos (solo si ese campo no se debería repetir en ningún otro `INSERT`).

Comment: Si no lo colocaste como respuesta creeria que no hay problema